# How to Add Text Box to RDLC 2010 Report

Tags: asp.net, rdlc, report

I am a casual user of the RDLC report control in VS 2005 Web Application, it seemed straightforward. I could set a report data source, then just drag a field into the report body as a text box.

In VS 2010, dragging a field onto a report does not seem to work.  I can drag a field into a cell in a table I've added to the report, but when I drag a field onto the report body, rather than show the field name in the text box, I see <> there.

In the expression box, the field looks like =First(Fields!state.Value, "TestDataSet"), but there is a squiggly red line under Field!stata, and no help to say what the problem is.  The fields in the table right next to it seem OK.  In the text box I can pick the field from a drop down, but I still get the error.

There is only one data set, containing one table connected to the report, so I don't see how there can be ambiguity or how the field could be out of scope..

It must be something simple.

Thanks
Mike Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are passing the correct dataset name (found in the report's Report Data tab if you aren't sure), be sure you are passing an IEnumerable (such as a List) as the data component of the ReportDataSource.  If you are passing a single object instead of a list, be sure to wrap it in an anonymous array, like this:

```
ReportDataSource reportDataSource =
                new ReportDataSource("TestDataSet", new[] { mySingleObject });
```